# I want to implement a download functionality in my UI. I want to create a directory chooser(React)

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, download

I should be able to select a directory and after clicking on okay/Download, it should call an API with the selected directory path in the backend(Springboot) which should copy a given file into that selected directory path.This is my react code:
`export const downloadReportZip = () => {
console.log("Downloading report initiated");

```
return (dispatch) => {
    // Create a directory chooser dialog
    const directoryChooser = document.createElement('input');
    directoryChooser.type = 'file';
    directoryChooser.setAttribute('webkitdirectory', ''); // For Chrome
    directoryChooser.setAttribute('directory', ''); // For Firefox
    directoryChooser.style.display = 'none';

    // Handle directory selection
    directoryChooser.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        const selectedDirectory = event.target.files[0]?.path; // Get the selected directory path
        console.log(selectedDirectory);
        if (selectedDirectory) {
            // Store the selected directory in a variable
            const directory = selectedDirectory;

            // Show a confirmation prompt to the user
            const isConfirmed = window.confirm("Do you want to download the report to the selected directory?");

            // If user confirms, make the API call to download the report
            if (isConfirmed) {
                // Make an API call to your backend endpoint with the selected directory path
                axios.post(`http://localhost:${serverPort}/downloadreport`, { directory })
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log('Report downloaded successfully:', response.data);
                        dispatch(fetchTestPlans());
                        // Optionally dispatch an action to handle success
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error('Error downloading report:', error);
                        // Optionally dispatch an action to handle error
                    });
            }
        }
    });

    // Click the input element programmatically to trigger the directory chooser dialog
    directoryChooser.click();
};
```

};`

This is the backend code:
`@Override
public void downloadReport(String selectedDirectory) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
String sourceFilePath = "D:/webconsolezip/pcheck-2.13.0-SNAPSHOT/project_output/Final_Result.zip";
File sourceFile = new File(sourceFilePath);
File destinationDirectory = new File(selectedDirectory);

```
        try {
            // Perform file copying operation
            FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(sourceFile, destinationDirectory);
            System.out.println("Report copied to: " + selectedDirectory);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Handle the exception as needed
        }
}`
```

The download chooser is getting opened but after selecting a directory and clicking ok nothing is happening.